# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity

I am trying to return the pets that are linked to a certain client but the message Sql = The function evaluation requires that all threads are executed

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (Session["nomeUsuarioLogado"] != null && Session["usuarioLogadoID"] != null)

        {
            int idcliente = new LoginController().Clientes(this);

            var consultar = from Pets in db.pets
                            join c in db.clientes on Pets.id_pets equals c.id_cliente
                            where c.id_cliente == idcliente
                            select Pets;

            return View(consultar);


            //    return View(db.pets.ToList());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "login");
    }




}
```

Comment: Do you try it under debug?

Comment: yes this message appears when debugging

Comment: responsei debug SELECT `Extent1`.`id_pets`, `Extent1`.`id_cliente`, `Extent1`.`nome`, `Extent1`.`Sexo`, `Extent1`.`especie`, `Extent1`.`raca`, `Extent1`.`idade`, `Extent1`.`descricao`, `Extent1`.`imagem` FROM `pets` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `clientes` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`id_pets` = `Extent2`.`id_cliente` WHERE `Extent2`.`id_cliente` = @p__linq__0

Comment: So the problem is that you see the message `The function evaluation requires that all threads are executed` and you want to see object properties?

Comment: From what I discovered it must be some query error because when the client id and pet id is the same in the pets table it returns the pet linked to the user, however when the pet id is different it doesn't work.

Comment: Pretty unbelievable explanation. More likely that you stop execution at different times and sometimes the query is fast enough to be evaluated. Also, some extensions can cause such issues, for example, Resharper does.

Comment: I found out it was just a mistake of mine to query the tables was comparing the values ​​incorrectly.